# Most frequent character in range

Tags: c++, character, complexity-theory, frequency, mode

I have a string `s` of length `n`. What is the most efficient data structure / algorithm to use for finding the most frequent character in range `i..j`?

The string doesn't change over time, I just need to repeat queries that ask for the most frequent char among `s[i]`, `s[i + 1]`, ... , `s[j]`.

Comment: what is the expected length of the string and of the intervals you are interested in

Comment: @Ivaylo It looks like that is variable.

Comment: Size of n is about 10^6 and I'll need about 10^6 queries as well.

Comment: ASCII, other single-byte charset or Unicode?

Answer (score 10):

An array in which you hold the number of occurences of each character. You increase the respective value while iterating throught the string once. While doing this, you can remember the current max in the array; alternitively, look for the highest value in the array at the end.

Pseudocode

```
arr = [0]
for ( char in string )
   arr[char]++
mostFrequent = highest(arr)
```

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev add an answer :)

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I don't see how that's more efficient - it's basically the exact same answer.

Comment: He's creating a multi-dim array.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I might have missunderstood your answer but it seems to me the complexity of your answer is O(N*Q) while I have O(N + L*Q) where L is the size of the alphabet and Q - number of queries.

Comment: I think the real problem here is that the OP didn't define efficient. Does it need to be efficient in terms of computation or storage?

Comment: +1 this is the most time efficient, but sorting + counting highest element is more space efficient (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to get efficient results on intervals, you can build an integral distribution vector at each index of your sequence. Then by subtracting integral distributions at j+1 and i you can obtain the distribution at the interval from s[i],s[i+1],...,s[j].

Some pseudocode in Python follows. I assume your characters are chars, hence 256 distribution entries.

```
def buildIntegralDistributions(s):
    IDs=[]        # integral distribution
    D=[0]*256
    IDs.append(D[:])
    for x in s:
        D[ord(x)]+=1
        IDs.append(D[:])
    return IDs

def getIntervalDistribution(IDs, i,j):
    D=[0]*256        
    for k in range(256):
        D[k]=IDs[j][k]-IDs[i][k]
    return D

s='abababbbb'
IDs=buildIntegralDistributions(s)
Dij=getIntervalDistribution(IDs, 2,4)

>>> s[2:4]
'ab'
>>> Dij[ord('a')]  # how many 'a'-s in s[2:4]?
1
>>> Dij[ord('b')]  # how many 'b'-s in s[2:4]?
1
```

Comment: I believe I have explained the same idea in my answer

Comment: I thought about that, but that wouldn't be efficient, unless there's a really quick way of subtracting distributions. Thanks.

Comment: @user2007674: the applicability of this idea will of course depend on the length of your intervals. If your intervals are shorter than the number of characters in your alphabet, then it will be more efficient to recalculate the distribution from scratch.

Comment: @Ivaylo: yes, it's the same idea!

Answer (score 2):

Do a single iteration over the array and for each position remember how many occurances of each character are there up to that position. So something like this:

```
"abcdabc"
```

for index 0:

```
count['a'] = 1
count['b'] = 0
etc...
```

for index 1:

```
....
count['a'] = 1
count['b'] = 1
count['c'] = 0
etc...
```

for index 2:

```
....
count['a'] = 1
count['b'] = 1
count['c'] = 1
....
```

And so on. For index 6:

```
....
count['a'] = 2
count['b'] = 2
count['c'] = 2
count['d'] = 1
... all others are 0
```

After you compute  this array you can get the number of occurances of a given letter in an interval (i, j) in constant time - simply compute `count[j] - count[i-1]` (careful here for `i = 0`!).

So for each query you will have to iterate over all letters not over all characters in the interval and thus instead of iterating over 10^6 characters you will only pass over at most 128(assuming you only have ASCII symbols).

A drawback - you need more memory, depending on the size of the alphabet you are using.

Comment: `A drawback - you need more memory, depending on the size of the alphabet you are using.` Understatement of the year I think for 10^6 strings of size 10^6...

Comment: That makes sense, and I have only lowercase alphabet characters in my string. However, this would take about 26 million operations for a 10^6 length string. This is reasonably quick, but I was wondering if there's a quicker solution.

Comment: @crush no not of size 10^6 but of size of the alphabet, at most 128, I guess at most 52 in a common case scenario.

Comment: @user2007674 I can't think of a faster solution, sorry :(

Comment: You have a multi-dim array: arr[index][char]. there can be 10^6 indices.

Comment: @crush yes but character is of size 26 as it seems. So I need 26 million integers or about 100 MB of RAM for this solution. We sacrifice memory for speed.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev for each string?

Comment: @crush there is a single string and you want to find the most frequent character in one of its substrings.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23311/discussion-between-ivaylo-strandjev-and-crush)

Comment: Mmmmm... 100 MB seems a little too much. I'd like it to run within 1 second, but not with that huge memory sacrifice. That's indeed why my problem is tricky. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your algorithmic requirements in terms of space and time complexity.

If you insist on `O(1)` space complexity, just sorting (e.g. using lexicographic ordering of bits if there is no natural comparison operator available) and counting the number of occurances of the highest element will give you `O(N log N)` time complexity.

If you insist on `O(N)` time complexity, use @Luchian Grigore 's solution which also takes `O(N)` space complexity (well, `O(K)` for `K`-letter alphabet).

Comment: Good point, by default I think of "most efficient" as "most time-efficient".

Answer (score 0):

```
string="something"
arrCount[string.length()];
```

after each access of string call freq()

```
freq(char accessedChar){
arrCount[string.indexOf(x)]+=1
}
```

to get the most frequent char call the `string.charAt(arrCount.max())`

Answer (score 0):

assuming the string is constant, and different `i` and `j` will be passed to query occurences.

If you want to minimize processing time you can make a

```
struct occurences{
    char c;
    std::list<int> positions;
};
```

and keep a `std::list<occurences>` for each character. for fast searching you can keep `positions` ordered.

and if you want to minimize memory you can just keep an incrementing integer and loop through `i` .. `j`

Answer (score 0):

The most time-efficient algorithm, as has been suggested, is to store the frequencies of each character in an array. Note, however, that if you simply index the array with the characters, you may invoke undefined behaviour. Namely, if you are processing text that contains code points outside of the range 0x00-0x7F, such as text encoded with UTF-8, you may end up with a segmentation violation at best, and stack data corruption at worst:

```
char frequncies [256] = {};
frequencies ['á'] = 9; // Oops. If our implementation represents char using a
                       // signed eight-bit integer, we just referenced memory
                       // outside of our array bounds!
```

A solution that properly accounts for this would look something like the following:

```
template <typename charT>
charT most_frequent (const basic_string <charT>& str)
{
    constexpr auto charT_max = numeric_limits <charT>::max ();
    constexpr auto charT_min = numeric_limits <charT>::lowest ();
    size_t frequencies [charT_max - charT_min + 1] = {};

    for (auto c : str)
        ++frequencies [c - charT_min];

    charT most_frequent;
    size_t count = 0;
    for (charT c = charT_min; c < charT_max; ++c)
        if (frequencies [c - charT_min] > count)
        {
            most_frequent = c;
            count = frequencies [c - charT_min];
        }

    // We have to check charT_max outside of the loop,
    // as otherwise it will probably never terminate
    if (frequencies [charT_max - charT_min] > count)
        return charT_max;

    return most_frequent;
}
```

If you want to iterate over the same string multiple times, modify the above algorithm (as `construct_array`) to use a `std::array <size_t, numeric_limits <charT>::max () - numeric_limits <charT>::lowest () + 1>`. Then return that array instead of the max character after the first for loop and omit the part of the algorithm that finds the most frequent character. Construct a `std::map <std::string, std::array <...>>` in your top-level code and store the returned array in that. Then move the code for finding the most frequent character into that top-level code and use the cached count array:

```
char most_frequent (string s)
{
    static map <string, array <...>> cache;

    if (cache.count (s) == 0)
        map [s] = construct_array (s);
    // find the most frequent character, as above, replacing `frequencies`
    // with map [s], then return it
}
```

Now, this only works for whole strings. If you want to process relatively small substrings repeatedly, you should use the first version instead. Otherwise, I'd say that your best bet is probably to do something like the second solution, but partitioning the string into manageable chunks; that way, you can fetch most of the information from your cache, only having to recalculate the frequencies in the chunks in which your iterators reside.

Answer (score 0):

The **fastest** would be to use an [`unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) or similar:

```
pair<char, int> fast(const string& s) {
    unordered_map<char, int> result;

    for(const auto i : s) ++result[i];
    return *max_element(cbegin(result), cend(result), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) { return lhs.second < rhs.second; });
}
```

The **lightest**, memory-wise, would require a non-constant input which could be sorted, such that [`find_first_not_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) or similar could be used:

```
pair<char, int> light(string& s) {
    pair<char, int> result;
    int start = 0;

    sort(begin(s), end(s));
    for(auto finish = s.find_first_not_of(s.front()); finish != string::npos; start = finish, finish = s.find_first_not_of(s[start], start)) if(const int second = finish - start; second > result.second) result = make_pair(s[start], second);
    if(const int second = size(s) - start; second > result.second) result = make_pair(s[start], second);
    return result;
}
```

It should be noted that both of these functions have the precondition of a non-empty string. Also if there is a tie for the most characters in the string both functions will return the character that is lexographically first as having the most.

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a59e6b7e269e3e64)