# Most frequent element in fixed width ranges - linear time

Tags: performance, algorithm, language-agnostic

#### The Problem:

I have an array A of N integers. For every i (i < N-M), for the range i..M, I need to find the element that occurs the most number of times.

Every element A[i] is between 0 and 10000.
But N <= 5*10<sup>6</sup> and M <= 5*10<sup>5</sup>

#### My Solution:

I have a O(N log<sub>2</sub>(max(A[i])) solution:

Create a binary heap storing the number of occurrences of every value and update it appropriately when moving on to the next M elements.

**I need a faster solution** which takes time linear in N, the number of elements.

---

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934468/most-frequent-of-every-n-elements-in-c) which is very similar to mine but has lower constraints, the solutions discussed there are not fast enough.

Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502939/most-frequent-character-in-range) which is similar to mine, but the solutions assume that there are at most 128 values of A[i].

I have also looked at other similar questions discussed here, but none of them seem to have a solution that works for me.

Comment: The O(N log 10000) is per request, right? Or is it preprocessing time (and how long per request then)? By the way - the usual idea with this type of thing is to do preprocessing and then get much faster than O(N) per request (as that would likely be too slow).

Comment: I am not clear if the ranges are overlapping.  How many outputs do you expect?  e.g. if N=100 and M=4, would you expect 25 outputs or around 100 outputs?

Comment: @Dukeling I have to precompute the most frequent element for every range i,i+M of the array.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz Yes the ranges are overlapping. I expect N-M+1 outputs

Comment: if N=100 and M=4 how do you get an answer for i=N-M=96…ie the range 96..4?

Comment: @user189, No, it will be the range i..i+M, 96..100

Comment: Your binary heap solution can be made very quick, because when moving on to the next range you have to modify two values, one must be increased by one, and one must be decreased by one.  Increasing and decreasing results in moving that element up or down the heap by typically no more than one level -> constant time.

Comment: @pentadecagon If there are many elements equal to the same value then increasing and decreasing will be O(height), I want the solution to run in 2-3 seconds

Comment: N is 5*10^6 time log(10000) is just 65*10^6, which is very fast, with CPU speed is normally 10^8 operations per second (for programming contest)

Comment: @A.06 And `moving on to the next M elements` is just move to the next element right? which means you only need to update at most two values at a time, or you mean different thing?

Comment: @PhamTrung Yes, I think the expected solution for this problem is O(N) because there was a 'Subtask' where N <= 5*10^5, which would have been for the N*log10000 solutions

Comment: @PhamTrung and if we are counting the operations then the heap might do more than 4*log(10000) operations for every increment/decrement.

Answer (score 1):

You can get to linear time with a specialized heap. This heap is nothing more than an (M + 1)-element array of linked lists. The linked list at index k is comprised of the elements that occur k times in the current window. To increase the count of an element, remove it from its present list and insert it into the one one higher. Check whether this element is now the most frequent. To decrease the count of an element, remove it from its present list and insert it into the one one lower. Check whether this element is no longer the most frequent by examining its former list.

In C, the structures needed could be declared like this.

```
struct Node {
    struct Node *prev, *next;
    long freq;
    int value;
} g_element[10000 + 1];

struct Node g_list_head[500000 + 1];

struct Node *g_most_freq;
```

Comment: But then I'll have upto M lists, how do handle lists that are empty?